# How to Update a K8s Deployment with More Replicas

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, linux-containers

I've created a simple K8s deployment with the `kubectl create` command

```
kubectl create -f k8-deployment.yaml
```

My `k8-deployment.yaml` file looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: mage-di
  name: mage-di
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mage-di
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mage-di
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: astorm/mage-di
        name: mage-di
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

This results in a single pod being started.

I want to tell my k8 cluster that more pods are needed to handle an expected traffic spike.

How should I do this? If I look at `kubectl help` I see there's an `edit` command that allows me to edit a deployment object's configuration, but this requires an interactive editor.  Also, I'm new to K8s and I'm unsure if editing a deployment in place and updating its replica count is enough to trigger the *proper* creation of new pods.  If I look at other `kubectl` commands I see there's also a `rollout`, `apply` and `patch` command that might do what I want.

Is there a canonically accepted way to do what I want, or is K8s the sort of tech where I just need to experiment and hope for the best?

Comment: If you have some way of measuring how much load you're handling, you can also look at setting up the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) to set the `replicas:` field automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. Either *imperative* - a quick command Or *declarative* - good for a production environment where you store your Deployment-manifest in Git.

**Imperative way**: (this will then diverge from what you have in your yaml-file)

```
kubectl scale deployment mage-di --replicas=2
```

**Declarative way**, edit this line in your Yaml file:

```
replicas: 2
```

then apply it to the cluster with:

```
kubectl apply -f k8-deployment.yaml
```

See also:

- [Declarative config management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/)
- [Imperative config management with commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/)